# Non-trivial homomorphisms to finite groups on fixed generating set

Tags: gr.group-theory

A group $G$ is **residually finite** if for each element $g\in G$ there exists a (surjective) homomorphism $f_g: G \rightarrow H_g$ such that $H_g$ is finite and $f_g(g)\ne 1$.

Consider the weaker condition where a finitely generated group $G = \langle x_1,\dots,x_n\rangle$ has the property that for each $x_i$ in this fixed generating set there exists a homomorphism $f$ onto a finite group $H$ such that $f(x_i)\ne 1$.

To see this is a weaker condition, assume $G$ is residually finite let $f:G\rightarrow H_{x_1}\times\cdots \times H_{x_n}$ by $f(g)=(f_{x_1}(g),...,f_{x_n}(g))$.

> However, is this condition strictly weaker? That is is there a
>   finitely generated group $G$ with a fixed generating set $X$ such that
>   for each element of $x_i \in X$ there is a homomorphism onto a finite
>   group $H_{x_i}$ but $G$ is not residually finite?

Comment: This question is possibly similar to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/244687/mapping-a-group-to-a-finite-group-s-t-the-image-of-each-generator-is-nontrivial. However, I had a different interpretation of what the question was asking then the posted anser, so I figured I would spin it off on it's own rather than edit the question when the intent was unclear. Also, I believe the answer for that question does not apply here, because this question imposes a fixed generating set.

Comment: My answer to the other question also answers this: take any finitely generated group which has a finite quotient but is not residually finite (such as BS(n,m), n,m >1). Then choose the generating set X in the way that I described.

Comment: @IanAgol: Looks like I was about half a minute ahead of your comment...

Answer (score 5):

Take the Baumslag-Solitar group $B(2,3) = \langle a,b\mid ba^2b^{-1}=a^3\rangle$. Take $X=\{a,b\}$.

Let $H=\langle r,s\mid r^5=s^2=1, sr=r^4s\rangle$, the dihedral group of order $10$. Since $sr^2s = (srs)^2 = r^8 = r^3$, and $s^{-1}=s$, then we get a homomorphism $f\colon B(2,3)\to H$ by $f(a)=r$, $f(b)=s$. Thus, $B(2,3)$ satisfies your weaker condition. But $B(2,3)$ is non-Hopfian, so it cannot be residually finite.